# Why can pyserial read data b'' without sending data to the opposite end?

Tags: python, pyserial

I encountered a strange problem. I used the pyserial module to read the serial port data，A serial tool is plugged into my PC, and nothing is connected to the other end of the serial tool. As a result, no data was sent to the serial port, but the serial.read() function can always read the data (b''). Why?

```
def read_com(serialport):
    while True:
        data = serialport.read(serialport.inWaiting())
        print(data)
        data = str(data, encoding="utf-8")
        #if data == "" or "&end" in data:
        if "&end" in data:
            return data
```

print result:

```
b''
b''
b''
b''
...
```

Comment: `serialport.inWaiting()` will return 0 if no data has been received, so you're calling `.read()` with a parameter of zero - and getting a zero-byte string in return.

Comment: @jasonharper nice, thanks.

Comment: @jasonharper this should be an answer so that this question can be closed.